# Xcode keyboard shortcuts for go to class from xib and from xib to class?

Tags: xcode, keyboard, xib, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut for jumping from the current xib file to it's class (ViewController)?  And back from it's class to it's xib file again?

I use ctrl-command-up/down all the time to to jump between header and source, be great to have one for the view xib also.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of quick ways to get to the XIB associated with a class.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>

This will open the jump bar to the current file. Assuming your XIB is named the same as your class -- which is usually good practice to do -- the matching XIB will be the next item in the list if you are in your implementation file, or two down if you are in your header file.

[image: Jump bar]

Alternately, you can open the XIB or StoryBoard associated with the file with one mouse-click if you have an `IBOutlet`.

See the outlet indicator next to the `IBOutlet`?

[image: IBOutlet indicator]

Click on it!

[image: IBOutlet XIB]

For additional Xcode shorcuts, a great resource is this PDF maintained in github:
http://cloud.github.com/downloads/Machx/Xcode-Keyboard-Shortcuts/Xcode_Shortcuts.pdf

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a keyboard shortcut for jumping from xib to corresponding class header file. But you can do that easily with a few mouse clicks:

1. Select a UI object in storyboard
2. Select "Identity inspector" in Utility Panel (3rd tab from left)
3. Click right-pointed arrow in the class name text field on top, which will take you to the header file
4. You can always go back and forth with two-finger swipe in Editor panel

Answer (score 1):

Most shortcuts can be seen here:
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html

And although that would be an awesome one, don't think it exists.